# how to resolve Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

I am trying to use MockK in my project,

when I try to verify an api call in the interface I get an error

> Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

this is my code

```
import com.example.breakingbad.api.ApiServiceInterface
import com.example.breakingbad.data.DataRepository
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.InjectMockKs
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import io.mockk.verify
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import org.junit.Test

class DataRepositoryTest {
    @MockK
    private lateinit var apiServiceInterface: ApiServiceInterface

    @InjectMockKs
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @Test
    fun getCharacters() {
        runBlockingTest {
            val respose = dataRepository.getCharacters()
            verify { apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi() } // HERE IS THE ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

DataRepository

```
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiServiceInterface: ApiServiceInterface
) {
    suspend fun getCharacters(): Result<ArrayList<Character>> = kotlin.runCatching{
        apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi()
    }
}
```

interface

```
interface ApiServiceInterface {
    @GET("api/characters")
    suspend fun getDataFromApi(): ArrayList<Character>
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15):

`verify` takes a standard function as an argument. You need to use `coVerify` which takes a suspend function as it’s argument.

Comment: marked the answer